# How to catch/Handle all uncaught exceptions in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am currently using doTry/doCatch blocks in my routes due to which I cannot use a global onException block.

However, I want to perform some business logic if camel route ever breaks (because of bad code or unexpected/untested scenarios). This will hopefully never happen, but I still want to handle for worse case.

I cannot have a java.lang.Exception in global onException block, also, I don't want to put an addition catch on every route.

Is there a specific method Camel calls before throwing uncaught exceptions and breaking route.

I see following log for Uncaught Exceptions:

```
2015-04-20 15:11:35,279 [Camel (fulfillmentOrderProcessor) thread #5 - seda://FulfillmentSedaQueue] WARN  o.a.c.component.aws.sqs.SqsConsumer [, ID-ip-10-180-252-213-54360-1429566855015-0-144]: Exchange failed, so rolling back message status: Exchange[Message: {... }]

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse string argument null
```

I looked at UnitOfWork.afterprocess. But this will not help as exchange will have exception even if I have handled it in camel route.

Comment: A good place to start is to read the documentation about error handling - http://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html

Comment: Lets assume you have multiple routes, you can define a specific rule for the specific rule, so insead for a global onException() you can handle from..().onException() for a single route. And as Claus mentioned, the error handling has the documentation for handling uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

by default, Camel will propagate the exception back to the caller, so you can catch the exception in whatever client code invokes the `seda://FulfillmentSedaQueue` route...

otherwise, the options on the server side (as you mentioned) are to use a global [onException clause](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) or route specific [doTry/doCatch](http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html) statements